# import sqlite table into mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

i am trying to import data from a table in sqlite onto a mysql table :

U exported the table of sqlite into a csv file. While importing the csv file into the mysql table, ihave the following error :

```
#1366 - Incorrect integer value: 'IDAPPRECIATIONL' for column 'idAppreciation' at row 1
```

`IDAPPRECIATION` is the column of the sqlite database and idAppreciation is the column of the mysql table they are both autoincrement.

Comment: Sounds like your CSV file includes the column names as headers and the import doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: i am not sure i anderstand what you said

Comment: I explained further in an answer below since I'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in your CSV file is likely the column names from your sqlite table.  Export without the column names or remove that first line.  Or during the import choose to skip the first line if you have the option.